# View layouts not displaying as expected

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin

i am at the point where i am going to loose it.

Problem: I inflate **GraphInWebView** into the layout called formDialog(some other file)
`formDialog.AddView(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.GraphInWebview, null));`

Alone this works perfect, but as soon as i attempt to inflate **LineItem** into **GraphInWebView**'s  **@+id/SideWidget** the latter never gets displayed.

I've check the source - the **LineItem** view is inflated but just does not nest in SideWidget

I have the following xml files.

**GraphInWebview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <WebView
      android:id="@+id/graphView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#00FF00"/>
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SideWidget"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000FF">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**lineItem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/Icon"
      android:maxHeight="5dp"
      android:maxWidth="5dp"
      android:id="@+id/icon"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Appointment: Appointment with Spur Cresta"
      android:id="@+id/appointmentTitle"
      android:minWidth="60dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Appointment: Appointment with Spur Cresta"
    android:id="@+id/appointmentText"
    android:minWidth="60dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**C#**

```
        //First inflate views to be injected into the default action bar
        formDialog.AddView(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.googleGraphInWebview, null));

        manageScheduleButton = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.ManageButton);
        locationalServicesButton = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.LocationalServicesButton);
        myProfileButton = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.MyProfileButton);
        myClientsButton = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.MyClientsButton);

        manageScheduleButton.Click += ManageScheduleMenuClick;
        locationalServicesButton.Click += locationalServicesButtonClick;
        myProfileButton.Click += myProfileButtonClick;
        myClientsButton.Click += myClientsButtonClick;

        formDialog.SetMinimumHeight(400);

        WebView graph = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.graphView);
        LinearLayout sideWidget = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.SideWidget);
        sideWidget.AddView(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LineItem, null));

        graph.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        graph.SetWebViewClient(new webView(formDialog));
        graph.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/graph.html");
```

Could anyone advise a way to solve this problem?

Regards

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.... The android's `layout_weight` was the key...

Given a view where two layouts both request, for example, `fill_parent`, the, for example, wanting them to share the view 40 - 60 you would assign to one `layout_weight=4` and to the other `layout_weight=6`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <WebView
      android:id="@+id/graphView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#00FF00"/>
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SideWidget"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000FF">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I post the finished code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <WebView
          android:id="@+id/graphView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_wight="2"
            android:background="#00FF00"/>
      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SideWidget"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_wight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000FF">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```